# mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer mv: try to overwrite ‘/usr/local/bin/composer’, overriding mode 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)?

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

**1-** Whenever I try to require anything by the composer in my laravel5 project it doesnt work .. and this error appears

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception '***PharException***' with message
>   '**phar "/usr/local/bin/composer"** has a broken signature' in
>   **/usr/local/bin/composer:23**

Stack trace:

```
#0 /usr/local/bin/composer(23): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
```

Thrown in **/usr/local/bin/composer** on line **23**

And when I try to move it I got that error

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
mv: try to overwrite ‘/usr/local/bin/composer’, overriding mode 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)?
```

When I press yes... it is said that access denied

by the way I am using Ubuntu ..

**2-** when i try to make illuminate/Html it doesnt work too because of the problem oof the composer too

Comment: Try to use `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: thnxx  a lot  mr Alexander Farber

Comment: I still want to know how can i solve the problem of the broken signature